# Samsung Galaxy A21s

Tags: home-screen

On my new Samsung Galaxy A21s I am trying to get it to open on the homepage every time I switch it on.
Presently, if I am on gmail and switch it off, and then turn it on it goes back to gmail.

What I want is that it always open in the homepage.

I unsuccessfully have tried to find a way to do this on internet.

Looking forward to your comments,
Regards, Mohan

Comment: "Switch on" means for you just switching on the display or do you mean booting up the phone?

Comment: By homepage and switch off/on if you mean home screen and sleep and resume your device, than use an automation app such as MacroDroid or Tasker. Very easy. You probably didn't get this answer because you are using incorrect terms for your objective.